# Ler a utilizar dados de um arquivo json externo sem jQuery

Tags: javascript, json

Eu tenho um arquivo json externo e quero usar os dados dele em varias funções que tenho, mas não estou conseguindo, só quando eu coloco todo o json dentro de uma variavel.

Pesquisei e acabei e achando esse exemplo:

```
function fetchJSONFile(path, callback) {
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        if (callback) callback(data);
      }
    }
  };
  httpRequest.open('GET', path);
  httpRequest.send();
}

fetchJSONFile('js/newwordlist.json', function(data){
  console.log(data);
});

console.log(data); //Nao retorna
```

Esse 1º console.log(data); retorna exatamente o que eu quero e como eu quero, mas já o segundo não resulta nada. Já tentei definir um var data; antes de tudo isso mas ainda não funciona.

Obs.: Não estou usando jQuery em nenhuma parte do projeto e acho que não seria bom chamar a biblioteca inteira só pra chamar o json.

Links:

JS: [selecttheme.js GitHub](https://github.com/teteusix/derdiedasdeutsch/blob/master/js/selecttheme.js)

JSON: [newwordlist.json GitHub](https://github.com/teteusix/derdiedasdeutsch/blob/master/js/newwordlist.json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para funcionar a variável global com AJAX você deve fazer uma requisição asincrona.

Apenas mude esta linha:

```
httpRequest.open('GET', path, false);
```

Caso contrário ele não funciona, pois ao printar a variavel no console, ela ainda não teve seu valor atribuido. Porém essa prática não tem sido recomendada.

Quando você executa o código da forma abaixo, ele parece a principio não conseguir printar o valor a tempo:

```
dataJ = '';

function fetchJSONFile(path, callback) {
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        if (callback) callback(data);
      }
    }
  };
  httpRequest.open('GET', path, false);
  httpRequest.send();
}

fetchJSONFile('json.json', function(data){
  dataJ = data;
  console.log(dataJ);
});
console.log(dataJ);
```

Porém se você for no inspect do navegador e escrever `dataJ` ele retornará tudo. O que significa que as funções que irão trabalhar com os valores ao decorrer das ações do usuário irão pegar os dados sem problema.

Eu particularmente utilizaria o `callback` para usos do retorno no carregamento da página, e depois do carregamento você pode utilizar a variavel global dataJ sem problemas também.

Comment: Agora já deu uma iluminada no que e como posso fazer, vou dar uma pesquisada melhor sobre o uso de callback porque o inspect do navegador já me "xingou". Obrigado

Comment: O inspect xinga por causa do assincrono. Por isso eu nem utilizaria ele. Faria no callback que seria nas linhas dentro da chamada do fetchJSONFile ali.